# git svn - get missing svn commits?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, git-svn version 1.9.1 (svn 1.8.8). I tried to clone https://sourceforge.net/p/searchmonkey/code/HEAD/tree/, using:

```
git svn clone https://svn.code.sf.net/p/searchmonkey/code -T trunk -b branches -t tags --prefix=origin/ searchmonkey-code-svngit
```

That process ended like this:

```
...
r850 = 3b98c1c32c0043184313828780c02ed7c2d85a7e (refs/remotes/origin/shawno)
    M   searchmonkey_2_x_x/util.h
    M   searchmonkey_2_x_x/mainwindow.ui
    M   searchmonkey_2_x_x/tab.cpp
    M   searchmonkey_2_x_x/mapped.cpp
    M   searchmonkey_2_x_x/find.h
    M   searchmonkey_2_x_x/grep.cpp
    M   searchmonkey_2_x_x/matcher.cpp
    M   searchmonkey_2_x_x/matcher.h
    M   searchmonkey_2_x_x/mainwindow.cpp
r851 = b3fe25fdacad270432f1a2f7b5876b83b54d2387 (refs/remotes/origin/shawno)
Checked out HEAD:
  https://svn.code.sf.net/p/searchmonkey/code/trunk r365
error closing pipe: Bad file descriptor at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 0.
error closing pipe: Bad file descriptor at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 0.
```

Now, when I `cd searchmonkey-code-svngit` and issue `gitk --all`, I see the latest commit is r851, to which I've reset `master`. So now, the status is:

```
$ git svn info
Path: .
URL: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/searchmonkey/code/branches/shawno
Repository Root: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/searchmonkey/code
Repository UUID: 937bcc44-791b-0410-a411-b6e56c9656c8
Revision: 851
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: shawno
Last Changed Rev: 851
Last Changed Date: 2011-05-06 04:01:08 +0200 (Fri, 06 May 2011)
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git log -1
commit b3fe25fdacad270432f1a2f7b5876b83b54d2387
Author: shawno <shawno@937bcc44-791b-0410-a411-b6e56c9656c8>
Date:   Fri May 6 02:01:08 2011 +0000

    minor changes before move working copy to non-system drive

    git-svn-id: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/searchmonkey/code/branches/shawno@851 937bcc44-791b-0410-a411-b6e56c9656c8
$ git svn log -1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r851 | shawno | 2011-05-06 04:01:08 +0200 (Fri, 06 May 2011) | 2 lines

minor changes before move working copy to non-system drive

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

... however, the sourceforge page says:

> tags     2011-05-07  shawno  [r852] 2.0.1 never got released

... so, basically, I'm missing r852 from this project's Sourceforge svn, as the last one cloned by `git svn` is r851. I tried doing:

```
$ git svn fetch
$ git svn rebase
Current branch master is up to date.
creating empty directory: install_msi/cache.upx/tmp
creating empty directory: sm_no_gui/release
$ git svn rebase
Current branch master is up to date.
```

... and still, the latest commit is r851.

How can I get the missing r852 commit into this git svn repository?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I got it: if I click on [[r852] 2.0.1 never got released](https://sourceforge.net/p/searchmonkey/code/852/), then I can see:

> removed   /tags/searchmonkey_v2.0.1
>   /tags/searchmonkey_v2.0.1
>   File was removed.

... so it's an entry saying that a file got removed; otherwise on https://sourceforge.net/p/searchmonkey/code/852/tree/, the `branches` item says:

> branches     2011-05-06  shawno  [r851] minor changes before move working copy to non-s...

... so indeed, r851 *is* the latest version - so, all is fine...

Comment: You can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

SVN commits that delete a tag or branch will not be visible as commits in the git-svn clone. But you should see the effect as the tag or branch should be deleted or at least renamed to something that makes clear that it was deleted in SVN, I'm not 100% sure.